# Can I make Python check my list to see if user input contains strings in my list using if statements? If not are there any alternatives?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

Beginner with Python but I wanted to use a list to contain multiple potential string responses that the user may give in the input.

```
def Front_Door():
    print("Welcome to the Party Friend!")
    Emotional_state = input("How are You Today?  ")
    Positive_Emotion = ["good", "fine", "happy"]
```

I tried to use an if statement to get python to check through my list to see if the input contained any of the strings listed in the e.g. I gave.

```
if Positive_Emotion in Emotional_state:
    print("That's Great! Happy to have you here!")
```

The code still manages to prompt me for `Emotional_state` but it just repeats the question one more time, if I respond with one of then strings I've listed again it gives me this error:

```
if Positive_Emotion in Emotional_state:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I'm guessing there is a method to make Python search through my list of strings and cross reference it with my inputs and give me the response I want?

Any help is appreciated :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if the whole list is in the string!
What you probably want to do is check if any of the items in the list are in the string.

Something like:

```
if any( [emotion in Emotional_state for emotion in Positive_Emotion] ):
    print("That's Great! Happy to have you here!")
```

This will check each emotion in the list, and if **any** of them are in the string it will return True.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, although I'm curious, do you know if there is a way that I can add a large word list to the positive_emotion variable? So that the emotional_state input can be a bit more flexible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm all too late to the party, but here are my two cents.

You only need Positive_Emotion and Emotional_state to switch places in your if statement, so that it becomes:

```
if Emotional_state in Positive_Emotion:
        print("That's Great! Happy to have you here!")
```